# How to retrieve list values from overriden methods

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, mvp

I have an MVP setup where the presenter populates two RecyclerViews separately with the following methods:

```
@Override
public void populateFollowsRV(List<FollowsRVModel> userDataList) {
    followsList.addAll(userDataList);
    followsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void populateFollowedByRV(List<FollowsRVModel> userDataList) {
    followedByList.addAll(userDataList);
    followedByAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

I have a separate third method in which I would like to retrieve the lists contents of followsList and followedByList, I have tried to declare a global variable called listOne in the Fragment class and then storing the contents of followsList/userDataList when populateFollowsRV() is called in order to have the contents accessible by other methods in the class but this doesn't seem to work:

```
//Declare listOne inside the Fragment class
private List<FollowsRVModel> listOne = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public void populateFollowsRV(List<FollowsRVModel> userDataList) {
    followsList.addAll(userDataList);
    followsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    //Assign the contents of userDataList to listOne when the presenter calls populateFollowsRV()
    listOne = userDataList;
}
```

listOne still appears to be empty after this.

> Third Method

```
public void populateNonFollowersRV() {
   //To test wether listOne has any content
   String.valueOf(listOne.size()));
}
```

Comment: Your override method seems to be OK. Could you post your third method

Comment: I have updated the question with the third method, at the moment it doesnt do much apart from get the size of listOne which appears to be empty, but has some content when you check the size inside the override methods

Comment: If followsList have data then listOne do supposed to have list of data. If listOne is empty, try adding data from followList rather than userDataList